# How to get EMF flux in the torque equation of a motor?

Tags: motor, pmsm

I have a question on field oriented control of electric motor drive.

I have been looking at derivation from 3phase to 2phase dq electrical matrix formula, but most of them stop at the torque equation where I don't understand thoroughly.

**Question: How can I get the EMF flux in the torque equation of a motor?**

With reference to this video "[Motor Control From Scratch - Part5 | DQ-model of PMSM motor & Understanding Torque Equation 8:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFCBQTuMOa0)", here is the torque equation of a synchronous motor:
[image]

Where p is the pole number, PSI is the inductance.  If the motor is salient or the command of id is zero, we can reduce the equation to only the first term

[image]

The control concept is to control iq to get desired torque. But what does that flux mean? Can I get it from motor specification, or how can I get this? I know that flux is equal to the inductance times the current, but what kind of inductance should I measure in this case? What current exactly should I multiply? Would it be a mutual inductance LM*cos(theta) multiply with current iq?

Appreciate any guidance or reference link to learn these motor drive concept.

Comment: You won't get the flux, rather  motor constants kt and/or kv.

Answer (score 1):

The top equation you are showing are for a permanent magnet synchronous reluctance motor. The bottom equation is for a permanent magnet synchronous motor (no saliency) The change in fluxlinkage \$\psi\$ in units of Weber is the term you are confused about cause it is written unintuitively in your equation. To understand it you need to understand Faradays Law and Gauss Law.

Fardays Law says that a changing flux with respect to time in a coil creates a voltage. \$\psi\$ is the total amount of magnetic flux in Weber [Wb] going through a coil in the motor. This is commonly called the "fluxlinkage". Faradays law can be represented several ways, but mainly what you need to understand is that the fluxlinkage changes with the rotor position \$\theta\$. This is key!!

\begin{equation}
EMF=\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\frac{d\psi}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{d\psi}{d\theta}\omega
\end{equation}

Lets move onto gauss law so you can understand the fluxlinkage concept better. Magnets create a magnetic field density \$B\$ which has units Wb/m^2. Faradays law says that if you take the coils area \$A\$ and multiply by the magnetic field density, then you will have the fluxlinkage, for that specific position.

\begin{equation}
\psi=\int B \cdot dA
\end{equation}

So putting this together. Torque is generated when there is a gradient in the fluxlinkage (i.e the amount of flux changes with the rotor position). Starting with power you see that you can get to toque by eliminating rotor speed \$\omega\$ from both sides.

\begin{equation}
Power=\tau\omega=EMF*I=\frac{d\psi}{d\theta}\omega*I
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Torque=\tau=\frac{d\psi}{d\theta}*I
\end{equation}

Theres a little more. When controlling the motor using FOC you are linearizing the dynamics of the machine, and operating the motor at its peak torque which occurs when the fluxlinkage gradient is largest, so the \$\frac{d\psi}{d\theta}\$ just becomes a constant.

Your equation should actually look like this:

\begin{equation}
Torque=\tau=max(\frac{d\psi}{d\theta})\frac{3}{2}pi_q
\end{equation}

Comment: But how do I know this maximum flux linage gradient? To control the motor using the last equation, Torque is the output, iq is the command input. But if we don't know about the maximum torque, how do we get the desired output? Is it by a hall sensor or by reading coil voltage?

Comment: This is a good question. The maximum flux linage gradient occurs on the quadrature axis (Q axis). Typically the Q axis is centered between two magnets. While the direct axis (D axis) which has a flux linage gradient of 0 points down the center of a magnet. In field oriented control you need an encoder to measure the rotor position so you physically know where these axis are located. Every time the rotor position changes you need to adjust where you apply the current so you are aligning with the Q Axis so you get maximum torque.